# Correct syntax query insert in to table(MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know that this is mysqli, but im wondring how to get this query correct.
I want to insert username, besvarelse and modulid into table.
but if besvarelse is empty or null i want to write back message that its allready delivered.

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO oppgave(username, besvarelse, modulid) 
         select '$username', '$besvarelse', '$modulid'
         from dual
         where not exists (select modulid from oppgave where modulid='$modulid')";

$result=mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
      echo "<h1>Allready delivered</h1>";
}else{
      echo "<h1>Delivery ok</h1>";
}
?>
```

Comment: *I know that this is mysqli,* no its mysql

Comment: sorry i was typing wrong, it mysql. can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: Remove quotes around here `'$modulid'`. should be `$modulid`

Comment: it oppgave who is the table name!

Comment: but it still not working

Comment: «if besvarelse is empty or null i want to write back message that its allready delivered»


Don't you like to check if $besvarelse is empty before sending a query?

Comment: if other user delidery same moodul is that someone other has delivered the if is written out

Comment: how will i output that?

Comment: just using one more `if` to check value of `$besvarelse`

Comment: And one more question: Is `$modulid` unique field in oppgave table?

Comment: modulid is not unique

Comment: every user should have the option to delivery 6 modul.

Comment: $tilkobling = kobleTil(); //trenger ikke oppgi databasenavn
if (!empty($besvarelse)){
$sql  = "INSERT INTO oppgave(username, besvarelse, modulid) 
         select '$username', '$besvarelse', '$modulid'
         from oppgave
          (select modulid from oppgave where modulid=$modulid)";
}
$result=mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
      echo "<h1>Du har levert denne modulen tidligere</h1>";
}else{
      echo "<h1>Besvarelse levert</h1>";
}
?>

Comment: i try this, get message that it delivered but it dont write to table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//«if besvarelse is empty or null i want to write back message that its allready delivered.»
//To check besvarelse we shold not use SQL, it is much better to check it with PHP

if ($besvarelse=='' or is_null($besvarelse)) {
    $resp = "<h1>Allready delivered</h1>";    
} else {
    $sql  = ......;
    $result=mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);
    if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
        $resp="<h1>Allready delivered</h1>";
    }else{
        $resp="<h1>Delivery ok</h1>";
}
echo $resp;
```

Comment: $tilkobling = kobleTil(); //trenger ikke oppgi databasenavn
if (!empty($besvarelse))  {
      
      
        // Define the query to inser the song request
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO oppgave (besvarelse, modulid, username) VALUES ('$besvarelse', '$modulid', '$username')");  

        if($insert) {
          
          echo "Insert was succesful<br>";
          
      
        }
    }
    else {
       
        die("Insert was not succesful");
       
}
?>

Comment: id try this now its writing evetrytime, but it allows duplikate :(

Comment: Check `$besvarelse` using `if` and leave sql query unchanged, like in your question.

Comment: @user3592679, how it «wont work»? What is the difference from expected result?